# Multiple extends in generic functions java

Tags: java, generic-programming, generic-list

I want to implement a simple sort function which sort the list and return the sorted list (very easy!). So I wrote this

```
public static <T extends List<? extends Comparable>> T sort(T objects)
{
    Collections.sort(objects);
    return objects;
}
```

The problem is when I try to sort a simple list it gives me this error

> Error:(19, 20) error: no suitable method found for sort(T#1)
>   method Collections.sort(List) is not applicable
>   (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
>   (argument mismatch; T#1 cannot be converted to List))
>   method Collections.sort(List,Comparator) is not applicable
>   (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#3
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>   where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
>   T#1 extends List declared in method sort(T#1)
>   T#2 extends Comparable declared in method sort(List)
>   T#3 extends Object declared in method sort(List,Comparator)
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>   CAP#1 extends Comparable from capture of ? extends Comparable

So what's the problem?!

Thanks in advance :)))

Comment: One of the problems is that if  `T extends P`, `List<T>` does not extend `List<P>`, so somehow your generic is not correct since you are expecting `T extends List<..>`.

Comment: And what is the purpose of that method in the first place? Why not call Collections.sort() in place?!

Answer (score 2):

As @Bejan George has pointed out, the generic type in this case should not be the the list but the comparable elements contained within the list.

The correct implementation would be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> sort(List<T> objects) {
    Collections.sort(objects);
    return objects; 
}
```